# Missing QueryableExtensions in EF 6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, extension-methods, iqueryable

I can't call the new `QueryableExtensions` (`ToListAsync`, `ForEachAsync`,...) provided with EntityFramework 6. But i can call others (`Include`, `Intersect`).

I've a reference to `System.Data.Entity`.
So apparently, i've an older version of `System.Data.Entity`, with the latest version of EntityFramework. Is it possible?

My code does not compile and I cannot see the `ForEachAsync` method in the object browser.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5, EntityFramework 6.1.3, Wpf.

**Edit**

Entity framework is installed :
[image: EF installed]

I've tried to Uninstall then Reinstall package many times, with a restart of visual studio. Still not working

**Edit**

In another project (referenced by this one), I can see the `IQueryableExtensions` needed in the object browser. If I add this project to my solution (before it was only a reference), the `IQueryableExtensions` needed are missing in the object browser.

Comment: You need a reference to `EntityFramework.dll` with `using  System.Data.Entity` statement at top of the page.

Comment: @Mathew please see my edit.

Comment: You have `using System.Data.Entity` statement too in the file you have this code?

Comment: @Mathew Yes, of course. 

And I've Resharper so if this using could be added, Resharper told me.

Comment: Is there multiple projects involved?

Comment: @Mathew Yes, one for unit testing (not really involved there), and another one for the database access, which also references EntityFramework 6.1.3.

Comment: If the project which has this code (`ToListAsync`) references `EntityFramework` and still you cannot compile that code, then I'm at loss, no more clue to what is actually happening. Maybe try a fresh demo project and see if it works there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your projects is probably targeting an older version of the .net framework.

I had this issue when a project was targeting .Net v4.0, update it to 4.5 or newer.
I also ran the command that others recommended after this.

```
update-package -reinstall EntityFramework
```

You can see what version of .Net is is targeting when you run the update-package command in the package console. For example output from my project when it was targeting 4.0

```
PM> Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
Attempting to gather dependencies information for multiple packages with respect to project '[My project]', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
```

and then with v4.5.2:

```
PM> Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
Attempting to gather dependencies information for multiple packages with respect to project '[My Project]', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
```

You update your .net version by:

```
right clicking on the project in the solution explorer, 
choosing "Properties"
on the Application Tab (default) from the DropDown list labeled "Target Framework" select 4.5 (or greater - I chose 4.5.2)
```

There is a chance you don't need to reinstall the package, however I reinstalled before checking if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the `EntityFramework.dll`. Remove the reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll` manually (if it is present).

Take a look at [QueryableExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx) on MSDN

With Nuget it should be simple, cause this will add the dependencies fro you

```
install-package EntityFramework
```

or use the update command

```
Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
```

This will install the latest version of Entity Framework (6.1.3)

Comment: I've already installed EntityFramework 6.1.3

`PM> Update-Package EntityFramework`

`No updates available for 'EntityFramework' in project 'TqlTool'.`

Comment: @ZwoRmi the try to reinstall it using update-package -reinstall EntityFramework

Comment: @ZwoRmi Also is there a reference to EntityFramework.dll in your project

Comment: Yes there is a reference to EntityFramework.dll. Nuget add this.
How to remove the `System.Data.Entity` from EntityFramework.dll? Is this possible?

Comment: @ZwoRmi yes SolutionExplorer->Select your project and open node "References"->Then remove System.data.entity using right-click on item

Comment: There is not `System.Data.Entity` in my references. Maybe because I don't use it, I only use the one included with EntityFramework.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have installed EntityFramework package when your project was targeting **.NET v4.0**. Even though you have migrated your project to **.NET v4.5**, the `QueryableExtensions` class still does not contain the async methods because the package was installed before migration.

Just reinstall the Entity Framework package.