# Case insensitive lambda expression

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, lambda

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Entity Framework 6, and trying to build a LINQ expression to fetch results based on a dynamic `WHERE` clause. The user can choose to search on `employeeId`, `securityId` (which is a string), or `lastName`. For last name, it should do a case-insensitive search, so user can enter upper or lowercase `searchValue`.

Here's what I've got:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>> 
    SearchEmployeesAsync(string selectedColumn, string searchValue)
{   
    var paramEmployee = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
    Func<EmployeeBase, bool> comparison = null;
    if (selectedColumn.Equals("employeeId"))
    {
        var employeeId = -1;
        int.TryParse(searchValue, out employeeId);
        comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(paramEmployee, selectedColumn),
                Expression.Constant(employeeId)),
            paramEmployee).Compile();
    }
    else
    {
        comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(paramEmployee, selectedColumn),
                Expression.Constant(searchValue)),
            paramEmployee).Compile();
    }

    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var query = (from e in context.Employees
            .Where(comparison)
            select new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                // Populate view model from entity object here
            });
        return await Task.Run(() => new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(query));
    }
}
```

How do I change the above code to make `comparison` to be case-insensitive for searches on `securityId` or `lastName` (both are strings on the database)? `securityId` or `lastName` are covered by the `else` block above. I'm also open to refactoring the code if there's a better way. One thing I don't want to do is use a third-party library to write dynamic `WHERE` clauses.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see securityID or lastname anywhere in your code...did you show us the right code?

Comment: The case sensitivity is actually controlled by the collation you use in your DB.  It's usually set to insensitive by default.

Comment: @rory.ap, those fall into the `else` condition. If it's `employeeId`, it's an `int` and no worries on case-sensitivity.

Comment: Try testing your code and seeing what SQL is generated to see if this is necessary, as @juharr mentioned, string comparison is handled within the DB, and often MS SQL is configured as case insensitive.

Comment: A side note. Since you are compiling your `comparison` expression to `Func`, the `.Where(comparison)` is resolved to `Enumerable.Where`, which means the whole `Employees` table is loaded in memory and the filtering is done by LINQ to Entities. From one side this would allow you to control the case sensitivity (which is not possible when the query is translated to SLQ), but from the other side the performance  would be incredible bad.

Comment: @IvanStoev, what do you recommend to resolve this?

Comment: Well, it would be better if you use `Expression<Func<..>>` in which case the query will be translated to SQL. Case insensitivity can be simulated (sort of) with `ToLower`.

Comment: @IvanStoev, do you mind throwing that in an answer for a n00b? :) Thanks.

Comment: `Func<EmployeeBase, bool> comparison = null;` should be `Expression<Func<EmployeeBase, bool>> comparison = null;` and then drop the `.Compile()`.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewWhited. Can you change case sensitivity here too?

Comment: By using `Func<...>` you are using `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`

Comment: @MatthewWhited, where would the `ToLower` go in this version?

Comment: No.  Just do what you are doing.  The issue is you are running your query in memory instead of in the database.

Comment: That breaks some of the calls to C# methods inside the SELECT, as it can't find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing it the easy way.  And I question the Task.Run, but since that wasn't part of the question, I left it alone.

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>> 
    SearchEmployeesAsync(string selectedColumn, string searchValue)
{   
  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
    var query = context.Employees.AsQueryable();

    switch(selectedColumn)
    {
      case "employeeId":
        var employeeId = -1;
        int.TryParse(searchValue, out employeeId);
        query = query.Where(e=>e.employeeId == employeeId);
        break;
      case "lastName":
        query = query.Where(e=>e.lastName == searchValue);
        break;
      case "securityId":
        query = query.Where(e=>e.securityId == searchValue);
        break;
      }
      query = query.Select(e=> new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                // Populate view model from entity object here
            });
        return await Task.Run(() => new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(query));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @RobertMcKee. How would you fix the `Task.Run`?

Comment: `return await (query).ToListAsync();` I think.  Which makes it truly async instead of what you were doing which is hiding a multi-threaded opeation in an async wrapper, which actually does the exact opposite of what async is for.

Comment: `.ToListAsync()` isn't available; only `.ToList()`

Comment: This is EF 6.0!

Comment: Are you sure it is 6.0, and you are referencing it as such, because the example from Microsoft here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx clearly uses `.ToListAsync()`

Comment: Just checked it in NuGet Package Mgr. > Installed: `6.1.3`

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5+?

Comment: The .NET version is 4.6

Comment: Try this thread and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346016/missing-queryableextensions-in-ef-6

Comment: @Alex Make sure you have `using System.Data.Entity;` included

Comment: As inefficient as it is, I had to run the query in memory using `var query = context.Employees.AsEnumerable();`. This was because of some C# methods being called in the SELECT, and they caused this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression. But this `switch` statement technique worked, adding the `WHERE` and then calling the `SELECT`. Thanks :)

Comment: Then instead of putting the `.AsEnumerable()` immediately after the table, put just before the `.Select`.  Like: `query = query.AsEnumerable().Select(`  this will get you a large performance boost.  Even better would be to do an initial `.Select(` that retrieves only the columns you need, do an `.AsEnumerable()` and then another `.Select(` that converts those columns and does your client-side functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the filtering to be applied in the database and not in the memory, it's essential to use `Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>` in `Where` clause rather than `Func<Employee, bool>` as in your code. The case insensitive comparison can be simulating by using `ToLower` method.

Also, as others mentioned it would be better to eliminate `Task.Run` call by using `ToListAsync` method from `System.Data.Linq.QueryableExtensions`.

With that being said, the implementation could be like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public async Task<ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>> 
    SearchEmployeesAsync(string selectedColumn, string searchValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    Expression left = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, selectedColumn);
    object value = searchValue;
    if (selectedColumn == "employeeId")
    {
        var employeeId = -1;
        int.TryParse(searchValue, out employeeId);
        value = employeeId;
    }
    else
    {
        // case insensitive
        left = Expression.Call(left, "ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
        value = searchValue.ToLower();
    }
    var comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(value)),
        parameter);

    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var query = context.Employees
            .Where(comparison)
            .Select(e => new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                // Populate view model from entity object here
            });
        var result = await query.ToListAsync();
        return new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev. One challenge of running it on the database: the SELECT calls local C# methods (issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression). But it's more efficient to run it on the db. So I'll keep plugging away at it :)

Comment: @Alex The best would be to eliminate those calls. But if you can't, then as usual with EF just use `AsEnumerable()` before the `Select` to switch the context - this way the filtering will be performed in the database and the rest in memory. And of course if you do that, switch back to `Task.Run` since there are no `Async` methods defined for `IEnumerable<T>`.